# Bricked my computer instead of the kindle fire?

Tags: power-supply, desktop-computer

I was rooting a kindle fire for a friend and now my pc doesn't work.

Symptoms are:

- inputs no longer work (usb or serial or dvi; hdmi produces a flicker
  but displays a message "no valid input" so I suppose we could strike
  that off as well...)
- Wi-Fi connection down - I noticed this first before I noticed
  anything else, it was the reason I reset my computer to discover the
  other problems
- fan ramps up to high and stays there. After 1-2 minutes it flutters
  between high and mid but will not enter idle

Because of this I'm unable to bring my computer to a point where I can perform a system restore.

I was in step 7 of the root instructions found at http://www.techhive.com/article/244303/how_to_root_your_kindle_fire.html
However I noticed the problem with the Wi-Fi a few steps sooner...

I have done a little bit of research into the symptoms and believe that it may actually be my power supply, but I wonder if it's not something I did, and if so how to fix it... Also if there are any other thoughts. I have rooted devices before and never had a problem like this.

Comment: Check to see if everything is still properly seated in the box

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please tell a little more about the computer. What OS are you using, what error messages are you seeing, etc. Does it work properly if booted to a Live CD? Have you run any diagnostics?

Comment: Its coincidence, I doubt it was anything you did. PC's break all the time, it just happened while you were using it.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the tutorial, although you are making some special usb mods/rules to what don't seem to be system files

> Step 6: Now that you have the SDK installed, you'll have to make two
>   quick modifications to it before you can root the Kindle Fire. First,
>   open up your User Account folder in Windows (C:\Users(Your Account
>   Name), find the new ".android" directory, and find a file called
>   adb_usb.ini. Open it up in Notepad, add a new line at the bottom of
>   the document, and type 0x1949. Make sure that string is on its own
>   line in the document, save it, and close it.

and

> Next, go to wherever you installed the Android SDK itself (probably
>   C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk), and navigate to the
>   \extra\google\usb_driver\ directory. Find the file called
>   android_winusb.inf and open it in Notepad. There, you'll want to take
>   the following lines and paste them immediately underneath the
>   [Google.NTx86] and [GoogleNTamd64] headings in the document:
>
> ;Kindle Fire %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0006
>   %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_1949&PID_0006&MI_01
>
> If Notepad doesn't let you overwrite android_winusb.inf when you're
>   saving it, save the edited version to your desktop, and then drag the
>   edited version over to the usb_driver directory to replace the old
>   version with your edited version. Windows may ask you for
>   Administrator permission to replace android_winusb.inf--don't worry,
>   it's fine.

and

> Step 7: Plug your Kindle into your PC. You'll need a micro-USB cable
>   to do this, which the Fire doesn't ship with, so you'll have to buy
>   that cable if you don't already have one that you use with your phone
>   or camera. Windows will probably automatically attempt to install a
>   driver for it, fail, and then mount it as a normal storage device.
>   That's fine, though we may have to change something there later.

If either adb daemon or sdk are starting on boot, reverting or eliminating those changes, specifically the mention of a windows automatic driver installation problem [STEP 7], you may need to boot from a live cd like hiren's boot cd and attempt maintenance from there, or get into your hardware/device manager and either identify the offender an uninstall it. Then ditch sdk and adb, and then refresh/scan hardware.